# plotting two matrix of same size on the same scale using plotyy

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 1'min frequency data set for wind speed and wind direction. I plotted them separately and it works fine since both the WS_daily and WD_daily matrices are of same size but when I use the plotyy function to plot both at the same time I get a scale difference. My wind speed goes up to 35 days for Jan and my wind direction plots till 27.5 days. Here is my code,

```
c = figure; 
x1 = WS_daily(:,1); 
x2 = WD_daily(:,1); 
y1 = WS_daily(:,2); 
y2 = WD_daily(:,2); 
[ax, p1, p2] = plotyy (x1,y1,x2,y2); 
grid on; 
box on; 
%set(ax(2),'Xtick',[]); 
set(ax(1), 'YLim', [0 40]); 
set(ax(2), 'YLim',[0 360]); 
set (gca, 'XLim',[0 31]); 
set (gca, 'XTick',[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31]); 
set (ax(1), 'Ytick', 0:10:40); 
set (ax(2), 'Ytick', 0:90:360); 
set(ax(2),'LineStyle', '.'); 
xlabel(ax(1), 
'Time of the day (LST)'); 
ylabel(ax(1), 'Wind Speed (m/s)','fontsize',13,'fontweight','b','color','b'); ylabel(ax(2), 'Wind direction','fontsize',13,'fontweight','b','color',[0,0.5,0]);
```

Comment: _My wind speed goes up to 35 days for Jan and my wind direction plots till 27.5 days._ What are the right `xlim` of the two set of data?

Comment: A picture of the graph will help understanding your problem. You can drop the picture on some repository (e. g. dropbox) and post the link; then a user with onough reputation can download it actually post it.

Comment: https://virginia.app.box.com/files/0/f/5109059298

Comment: For some reason I can't get the wind direction to plot as dots either now. I was able to with the same code!

Comment: Unfortunately I can not enter the web site todownload the picture; a login is required.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A6C86D4C8D7E8ED4!1160&authkey=!AANE4tjFXkzUBpY&ithint=file%2cfig

Comment: Looking at picture: it seems that "wnd speed data" range from 0 to 30 while "wind directon" from 0 to 29, Also the `xlabel` is "Time of the day" shouldn't be `xlim` (0 - 24)? Could be the problem due to the input data? What are: `x1(1), x1(end), x2(1), x2(end)'? Could you post also the input data?